# Angular 15 adding &quot in background-url

Tags: html, angular, background-image, urlencode

I have the following code to add an image as a background, but when rendered in the browser, the urls have the addition of the **&quot**, would anyone know why?

**Template**

```
<picture class="picture background-image" [style.background-image]="'url(' + this.componentParams.link + ')'"
  title={{this.componentParams.title}}>
</picture>
```

**Component**

```
 public componentParams: any = {
    link: "../../../assets/images/category/montagem-moveis.png",
    title: "Montagem de imóveis"
  };
```

**Render**

```
<picture _ngcontent-ng-c4105489152="" class="picture background-image" title="Montagem de imóveis" style="background-image: url(&quot;../../../assets/images/category/montagem-moveis.png&quot;);"></picture>
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide a screenshot with the current outcome?

Comment: @Dhia description updated with image, thanks

Comment: Related: *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*)

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're facing is related to how the browser is encoding special characters in the URL. In this case, the `"` character is being encoded as `&quot;`, which is causing the problem.

To fix this, you should use Angular's property binding syntax without concatenating the string manually. Modify your template code like this:

Template:

```html
<picture class="picture background-image" [style.background-image]="'url(' + componentParams.link + ')'" [title]="componentParams.title">
</picture>
```

In this updated code, we use the property binding syntax (`[...]`) for both `style.background-image` and `title`. By doing this, Angular will handle the correct encoding of special characters, and you should no longer see `&quot;` in the URL.

Additionally, there's no need to use `this` when accessing `componentParams` in the template, as Angular automatically knows that you are referring to the component's property.

With these changes, the rendered output should be:

```html
<picture _ngcontent-ng-c4105489152="" class="picture background-image" title="Montagem de imóveis" style="background-image: url(../../../assets/images/category/montagem-moveis.png);"></picture>
```

Now, the `style` attribute should contain the correct URL without the `&quot;` encoding.

Comment: Hello
I tried your suggestion but it keeps showing the quote in url:

<picture _ngcontent-ng-c4105489152="" class="picture background-image" title="Montagem de imóveis" style="background-image: url(&quot;../../../assets/images/category/montagem-moveis.png&quot;);"></picture>

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT